# How do I get full error messages out of webpack?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to use webpack to autoprefix / compile my scss. Here is my webpack.config.js (basically copy / paste of bootstrap's):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [
                    // require('precss'),
                    require('autoprefixer')
                ];
              }
            }
          },
          {
            // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

However if I have an undefined variable or some other error, the only detail I get back from `wp -w` is

> 0:0  error  Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

Which doesn't tell me anything. I'd like to know about files and line numbers, quantity, and type of the errors.

EDIT: I looked at `wp --help` and I tried `--debug` and `--log-level debug` but neither gets me where I want.

Comment: The `friendly-errors-webpack-plugin` could be helpful: https://github.com/geowarin/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin

Comment: In case somebody else is just getting started with webpack, add `mode: "development"` to your config. Then the actual errors will be available in the browser console, but not in the output of `wp -w`. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/